# php file_put_content to aws S3

Tags: php

i am trying to write a file to aws s3 which obviously is not working now.

in my code i now have the following where the signedurl is the complete s3 url

```
$url = ($signedurl);

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"PUT",
    'header'=> array ("Connection: keep-alive","Content-Lenght: ".$filesize,"Content-Type: audio/mpeg","Accept: */*")
  )
);
$filelocation = "/home/martin/Dropbox/data/track".date("dmY").'_MP3WRAP.mp3';

$contexta = stream_context_create($opts);
$afile = file_get_contents($url, false, $contexta);
$file = file_put_contents($filelocation, $afile);
```

What happens now is that the file is not being uploaded with the required headers and i dont see where this goes wrong.

Any help is appriciated

Comment: I would watch first your Content-Lenght typo. It should be ``Content-Length``

Comment: i missed that one but still no upload